# UIBezierPath onTouch Drawing Example with smooth draw line

Tags: iphone, ios

i want to smooth and curve draw line on finger touch and using only UIBezierPath.i am new for drawing concept in iOS and i need any example or code and how to do it like my requirement can any one guide me with greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one example for free hand drawing but one problem is it is not much smoother but you can have one starting point using [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/iOS-drawing) example.

Happy Coding :)